# Text Field and Label Editing Errors

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Before I get started, I have to say that this project marks the first in-depth use of Swift and XCode in my life. I started it about a week ago (and am honestly impressed with how far I've gotten). I do not know too much about what I'm doing but I'm willing to learn.

Now, onto my question.

I'm trying to get a text field from one view controller to change a label from another. I thought I did it right, but it kept throwing syntax errors and such at me. After fixing that, I would run the code and get a SIGABRT error. Here's my code.

Here's the label, under BasicViewController (this isn't all that's in BasicViewController, I just cut out what I thought was pertinent)

```
class BasicViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var NameField: UILabel!

    var NameText = String()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NameField.text = NameText
}
```

And here's the text field, under EditCharController. This is where the SIGABRT error happens. (also, same thing with the lack of code.)

```
class EditCharController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource  {

    @IBOutlet weak var NameTextField: UITextField!

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        var NameTextDest : BasicViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! BasicViewController //Specifically, this is the line that it happens at.

        NameTextDest.NameText = String(NameTextField.text)

}
}
```

Currently, XCode is telling me to change the var label to the let label, but even if I do that, it spits out this error.

```
Could not cast value of type 'UITabBarController'(?!?) (0x10310c8b0) to 'Project.BasicViewController' (0x1019a0060).
```

Last I checked, I didn't reference the UITabBarController anywhere in the code. Why am I getting this message?

Also any suggestions as to good in-depth tutorials will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Is your `BasicViewController` part of a `UITabBarController`?

Comment: Make sure the segue is going to a `BasicViewController`. This is telling you that the segue is going to a `UITabBarController`.

Comment: @Code I don't see `UITabBarController` anywhere in BasicViewController.swift. I _have_ a Tab Bar Controller in the storyboard, and it goes to the BasicViewController, otherwise I can't get the tabs to appear after exiting EditCharController. I have it set up so it goes like this: TabBarController > BasicViewController > EditCharController > TabBarController ... TabBarController automatically routes to BasicViewController, but to get to BasicViewController from EditCharController or EditCharController to TabBarController requires user input to avoid an infinite loop. Is that my problem?

Comment: So Basic and Edit are both tabs of a tab bar controller?

Comment: @Code Edit is not, but Basic is. To get to Edit, you have to tap "Edit" in the top left navigation bar of Basic. To get back to Edit, you tap "Save" in the nav bar which takes you to the Tab Bar Controller, which then takes you to Basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
let index = 0 // change this to the tab index of the BasicViewController.
let NameTextDest : BasicViewController = (segue.destinationViewController as! UITabBarController).viewControllers[index] as! BasicViewController

NameTextDest.NameText = NameTextField.text!
```

Comment: Well, it almost worked. It didn't stop the app dead cold, but now the label reads "Optional("[whatever the input is]")".

Comment: @JakeMcGee You could give my answer an upvote if you find it useful.

Comment: I did but because I made this account the day I posted this question and therefore I have less than 15 reputation, it won't show it.